# Issue with jQuery element targeting

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w1ok0p6o/5/) to my [document](http://pastebin.com/EpsgqLij) to hide the unneeded `rideshare-item` divs (instead of `rideshare-detail`) whenever the user performs a filtering operation. I think that it is down to the way in which I have targeted the div elements, but I am not sure.

Could someone please point me in right direction? How do I target the elements as seen in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1ok0p6o/5/) to my [document](http://pastebin.com/EpsgqLij)?

This is my code so far:

```
$('body').on('click', '#go-button', function(event){
    // Collect values
    var startAddress = $('.start-address').val();
    var destinationAddress = $('.end-address').val();
    // Only show matching pickup address and waypoint
    $('.rideshare-item').show();
    $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').each(function(a,b){
        var waypoint = $(b).attr('waypoint');
        // if found
        if((waypoint == startAddress) || (waypoint == destinationAddress)){
            return false;
        }
        // if not found
        else if($((waypoint != startAddress) && (waypoint != destinationAddress)) && a == $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').length-1) {
            $(this).closest('.rideshare-item').hide();
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: What's your question? And ... what is `a` in `a == $('.rideshare-detail .waypoint').length-1`?

Comment: Hi @PeterKA, check out the answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974852/hide-div-element-if-attribute-does-not-match-filter. I am trying to apply the code to my own document. Running into issues with the integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this :

```
$('#go-button').on('click', function(event) {
    var startAddress = $('.start-address').val();
    var destinationAddress = $('.end-address').val();
    $('.panel').hide().filter(function(i) {
        var waypoints = $(this).find('.waypoint');
        var w_1 = waypoints.filter(":first").data('waypoint');
        var w_2 = waypoints.filter(":last").data('waypoint');
        return w_1 == startAddress && w_2 == destinationAddress;
     }).show();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w1ok0p6o/6/)**

Please note that I changed the waypoints' HTML from `waypoint="..."` to `data-waypoint="..."`.